# Streamplot mgrid - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

I'm working in a project and I have to create a method to generate an image with an background and vector flows. So, I'm using the stream plot from **matplotlib**.

```
class ImageData(object):

    def __init__(self, width=400, height=400, range_min=-1, range_max=1):
        """
        The ImageData constructor
        """
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        #The values range each pixel can assume
        self.range_min = range_min
        self.range_max = range_max
        #self.data = np.arange(width*height).reshape(height, width)
        self.data = []
        for i in range(width):
            self.data.append([0] * height) 

    def generate_images_with_streamline(self, file_path, background):

        # Getting the vector flow
        x_vectors = []
        y_vectors = []
        for i in range(self.width):
            x_vectors.append([0.0] * self.height)
            y_vectors.append([0.0] * self.height)

        for x in range(1, self.width-1):
            for y in range(1, self.height-1):
                vector = self.data[x][y]
                x_vectors[x][y] = vector[0].item(0)
                y_vectors[x][y] = vector[1].item(0)

        u_coord = np.array(x_vectors)
        v_coord = np.array(y_vectors)

        # Static image size
        y, x = np.mgrid[-1:1:400j, -1:1:400j]

        # Background + vector flow
        mg = mpimg.imread(background)

        plt.figure()
        plt.imshow(mg, extent=[-1, 1, -1, 1])

        plt.streamplot(x, y, u_coord, v_coord, color='y', density=2, cmap=plt.cm.autumn)
        plt.savefig(file_path+'Streamplot.png')
        plt.close()
```

The problem is 'cause my **np.mgrid** should vary from -1 to 1 and have the **self.width** and **self.height**. But if do:

```
y, x = np.mgrid[-1:1:self.width, -1:1:self.height]
```

It doesn't work. And also don't know what this **j** means, but this seems to be important, 'cause if I this take off the **j** (even if with an static size), it doesn't work either. So, I'm wondering how I could do this **mgrid** to be dynamically, following the **self** size.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

`j` is for imaginary part of a complex number, and gives `numpy.mgrid` the [number of values to generate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html). In your case, here is what you shall write:

```
y, x = np.mgrid[-1:1:self.width*1j, -1:1:self.height*1j]
```

**Long answer**

`step` value in `np.mgrid[start:stop:step]` shall be understood as follows:

- if `step` is real, then it is used as stepping from start up to stop, not included.
- if `step` is pure imaginary (e.g. `5j`), it is used as the number of steps to return, `stop` value included.
- if `step` is complex, (e.g. `1+5j`), well I must say I don't understand the result...

The `j` is for an imaginary part.

Examples:

```
>>> np.mgrid[-1:1:0.5]  # values starting at -1, using 0.5 as step, up to 1 (not included)
array([-1. , -0.5,  0. ,  0.5]) 
>>> np.mgrid[-1:1:4j]  # values starting at -1 up to +1, 4 values requested
array([-1.        , -0.33333333,  0.33333333,  1.        ])
>>> np.mgrid[-1:1:1+4j]  # ???
array([-1.        , -0.3596118 ,  0.28077641,  0.92116461])
```

Comment: @pceccon No comment? Did my answer address your concern? If so, would you please accept it?

Comment: Accepted! Thank you very much! Sorry for the late. :S